# Connecting a 4G/LTE board/hat designed for a standard Pi 4 Model B to a CM4 carrier board

Tags: networking, pi-4, hat, compute-module-4, openwrt

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 as a normal raspberry OS system as well as a router / gateway for networking and to be able to get an internet connection via 4G. Now there are products that exist that do that already however they are a little on the large size for my application. I’d like something that can serve as a router/gateway using OpenWrt while getting internet via 4G that can be connected directly to the Compute Module 4 or through a carrier board.

I found [this Dual Gigabit Ethernet 5G/4G Base Board for Raspberry Pi CM4 from Waveshare](https://thepihut.com/products/dual-gigabit-ethernet-5g-4g-base-board-for-raspberry-pi-cm4) which appears to do what I want, however the horizontal footprint is still too big.

As an alternative I have found these very small carrier boards for the Compute Module 4.
[One is from a company called Seeed Studio](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Rapberry-Pi-CM4-Dual-GbE-Carrier-Board-p-4874.html) [the other is from a company called DFROBOT](https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-compute-module-4-iot-router-carrier-board-mini).
Both of these can do everything for my Compute Module 4 including the OpenWrt networking aspect but they both appear to lack the ability to get internet via 4G (correct me if I’m wrong). In which case I have found three dedicated 4G boards that hopefully can be used in conjunction with the two carrier boards from Seed Studios and DFROBOT in a stacked configuration for a small horizontal footprint.

The three dedicated 4G boards I have found which might be suitable are the following:

- [Sixfab - Raspberry Pi 3G/4G & LTE Base HAT](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-base-hat-3g-4g-lte-minipcie-cards/)
- [Waveshare - 4G pHAT for Raspberry Pi - LTE Cat-4/3G/2G with GNSS Positioning](https://thepihut.com/products/4g-phat-for-raspberry-pi-lte-cat-4-3g-2g-with-gnss-positioning)
- [Waveshare - 4G HAT for Raspberry Pi - LTE Cat-4/3G/2G with GNSS Positioning](https://thepihut.com/products/4g-hat-for-raspberry-pi-lte-cat-4-3g-2g-with-gnss-positioning)

The only problem with these boards is that they appear to be designed for a standard Raspberry Pi 3/4 Model B and attach directly onto the board. Clearly this isn’t possible for the Compute Module 4. And the two carrier boards I mentioned earlier from Seeed Studious and DFROBOT don’t look like they could accommodate any of the mentioned 4G boards. However on the Sixfab 4G board it says the following:

*"Without Header: If just the plugging Base HAT via micro USB cable to Raspberry Pi is enough for you, or you’ve already attached a bulky shield on Pi, or you don’t need UART communication or IOs, headerless HAT works greatly. To find out what you are missing without headers, take a look at the Pinout Diagram of the HAT, these pins will be unconnected."*

Which seems to imply you can just plug this 4G board into a USB which both the Seeed Studious and DFROBOT carrier boards have. However looking at the pinout diagram I’m not sure if this would work how I want it to and I’m still not sure if I could do the same for the other two 4G boards from Waveshare.

**To summarise;** Am I able to connect the three 4G boards listed above (or others) (designed for a Pi 4 Model B) to a Compute Module 4 carrier board such as the ones I listed from Seed Studios and DFROBOT such that I can get a 4G internet connection and be able to use OpenWrt for network configuration, to reduce my horizontal footprint in a stacked configuration?